# Find last event for each entity in Lucene

Tags: java, lucene

So I have events (documents) stored in a Lucene document store (version 6.2.1). Each document has a `EntityId` and a `Timestamp`.

There can be many documents with the same EntityId.

I want to retrieve the document which has the latest `Timestamp` for each `EntityId`.

Do I have to pull out every event and do this in Java? I had a look at faceting, but as far as I can see it is just for counts, not for max/min type aggregations

Answer (score 2, accepted):

What you try to do can be done with a [`GroupingSearch`](http://lucene.apache.org/core/6_2_1/grouping/org/apache/lucene/search/grouping/GroupingSearch.html) available from the artifact [`lucene-grouping`](https://mvnrepository.com/artifact/org.apache.lucene/lucene-grouping/6.2.1).

The `GroupingSearch` will group your documents by the provided group field (`EntityId` in our case) which have to be sorted otherwise on search you will get an error of the next type:

> java.lang.IllegalStateException: unexpected docvalues type NONE for
>   field '${field-name}' (expected=SORTED).

Then to be able to have the most recent document for a given `EntityId`, you will also need to have the field `Timestamp` sorted.

So for example if I index the documents as next:

```
String id = ..
long timestamp = ...
Document doc = new Document();
// The sorted version of my EntityId
doc.add(new SortedDocValuesField("EntityId", new BytesRef(id)));
// The stored version of my EntityId to be able to get its value later if needed
doc.add(new StringField("Id", id, Field.Store.YES));
// The sorted version of my timestamp
doc.add(new NumericDocValuesField("Timestamp", timestamp));
// The stored version of my timestamp to be able to get its value later if needed
doc.add(new StringField("Tsp", Long.toString(timestamp), Field.Store.YES));
```

I would then be able to get the most recent documents for a given `EntityId` as next:

```
IndexSearcher searcher = ...
// Some random query here I get all docs
Query query = new MatchAllDocsQuery();
// Group the docs by EntityId
GroupingSearch groupingSearch = new GroupingSearch("EntityId");
// Sort the docs of the same group by Timestamp in reversed order to get
// the most recent first
groupingSearch.setSortWithinGroup(
    new Sort(new SortField("Timestamp", SortField.Type.LONG, true))
);
// Set the limit of docs for a given group to 1 as we only want the latest
// NB: This is the default value so it is not required
groupingSearch.setGroupDocsLimit(1);
// Get the 10 first matching groups
TopGroups<BytesRef> result = groupingSearch.search(searcher, query, 0, 10);
// Iterate over the groups found
for (GroupDocs<BytesRef> groupDocs : result.groups) {
    // Iterate over the docs of a given group
    for (ScoreDoc scoreDoc : groupDocs.scoreDocs) {
        // Get the related doc
        Document doc = searcher.doc(scoreDoc.doc);
        // Print the stored value of EntityId and Timestamp
        System.out.printf(
            "EntityId = %s Timestamp = %s%n", doc.get("Id"),  doc.get("Tsp")
        );
    }
}
```

More details about [grouping](http://lucene.apache.org/core/6_2_1/grouping/org/apache/lucene/search/grouping/package-summary.html).

Comment: Ah! - I think the key bit of information I missed when I read the documentation is the `SortedDocValuesField` bit. I'll need to re-index, but ill give this a go and come back and mark the response when it works. Thanks!

Comment: Yeah im pretty sure its what I want. I'm currently trying to figure out how I can use `getAllMatchingGroups` because i am looking to group every entity, however I have no idea what to do with the returned Collection of BytesRef :s

Answer (score 0):

You could try using the [Collapsing query parser](https://cwiki.apache.org/confluence/display/solr/Collapse+and+Expand+Results) like this (not tested):

```
fq={!collapse field=EntityId max=Timestamp}
```

Or you could probably achieve the same with [Grouping](https://cwiki.apache.org/confluence/display/solr/Result+Grouping)

Comment: I am using Lucene, not Solr, unless I'm mistaken these are Solr specific.

Comment: ooops, sorry, I just looked at another Solr question and I didn' realize this was plain Lucene.